# "Фрактальный" интерфейс не имеет смысла?

Tags: c#, рекурсия, теория

В ходе устранения у себя катастрофического пробела в знаниях, набросал некий класс, примерно такой (не включаю в листинг конструкторы и методы, вопрос и так получается сложный для восприятия):

```
public class SomeFractal
{
        public int Generation;
        public SomeFractal Parent { get; private set; }
        public SomeFractal Root
        {
            get
            {
                if (Generation == 0) return this;
                else return Parent.Root;
            }
        }

    List<Fractal> Children {get;}
}
```

Делалось это для отработки рекурсивных алгоритмов, но я не об этом.

Возникла идея описать несколько "фрактальных" классов, различающихся деталями, и реализующих единый интерфейс, пусть будет IFractal. Интерфейс должен содержать основные свойства (родитель, корень, дочерние ветви).

Большинство свойств естественным образом возвращает объект класса, в котором они описаны (у нас фрактал, помните?), соответственно, если я хочу, чтобы они описывались в интерфейсе, он должен быть ковариантным. Получается примерно так:

```
interface IFractal <out T> where T : IFractal<T>
{
    T Root { get; }
    T Parent { get; }

    IEnumerable<T> Children { get; }
}
```

Собственно, проблем нет - интерфейс, конечно, реализуется классом, описанным выше:

```
class SomeFractal : IFractal<SomeFractal>
```

Проблемы начнутся, если я захочу где-то в другом месте использовать переменную типа `IFractal<T>`, чтобы абстрагироваться от конкретного реализующего класса. Ведь мне придётся указать параметр Т, который может быть только классом, реализующим IFractal - то есть, никакой абстракции не получается, это в данном случае тоже самое, что использовать непосредственно класс.

Есть ли способы обойти это ограничение?
Может быть, я не смог в ковариантность?

Прошу не обсуждать целесообразность практического применения, это чистое теоретизирование в образовательных целях.

**UPDATE**

Про нон-дженерики поясню на примере

```
interface IFractal 
 {
     IFractal Root { get; }
     IEnumerable<IFractal> Children { get; }
 }


 class Fractal : IFractal 
 {
     public IFractal Root { get {
             if (parent == null) return this;
             else return parent.Root;
         } }
     public IEnumerable<IFractal> Children { get; }
     private Fractal parent;

     private string prettyCoolField;

     public string GetRootField() {
         return Root.prettyCoolField;
     }
 }
```

`GetRootField()` Работать не будет, ведь у `IFractal` нет поля `prettyCoolField`. return `(Fractal)Root.prettyCoolField;` так же не работает. Или я некорректно приводу тип?

Comment: А зачем вам ковариантность? Это не придирка, а теоретический вопрос в образовательных целях. Если вы работаете с абстрактным интерфейсом `INonGenericFractal`, чего вам не хватает, для чего вам нужна ковариантность? `IEnumerable<INonGenericFractal>` и геттеры `Root`/`Parent` и так ковариантны.

Comment: Ну и у нас тут не считается хорошим тоном делать существенные изменения в вопросе, особенно после того, как дан ответ: это ставит отвечающего в глупое положение как бы. (Разве что ваша правка не инвалидирует ответ, тогда в порядке.)

Comment: @VladD, существенно был изменён только листинг, в соответствии с замечаниями Павла. Так же переформулировал заголовок. Сам вопрос, заданный в предпоследнем абзаце, остался неизменным.

Comment: @VladD, `IEnumerable<INonGenericFractal>` и геттеры будут относиться к типу `INonGenericFractal` (интерфейс), а не `NonGenericFractal` (реализующий класс) - то есть, это уже вроде как и не фрактал

Comment: @VladD сделал апдейт с примером неуниверсального интерфейса

Comment: А если так: http://pastebin.com/SfrUwHxu ?

Comment: Отлично, спасибо! Вы не могли бы вынести это в ответ?

Comment: Не вопрос, сейчас сделаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите с одной стороны класс, который представляет собой элемент дерева, дерево, а с другой стороны, интерфейс для чтения, который не зависит от самого класса, то вам нужно разнести данные и имплементацию интерфейса.

При этом проблем не возникает, поскольку getter-only-свойства и `IEnumerable<T>` и так ковариантны по типу `T`. В результате получаем обычный интерфейс:

```
interface IFractal
{
    IFractal Root { get; }
    IFractal Parent { get; }
    IEnumerable<IFractal> Children { get; }
}
```

и его реализацию:

```
class Fractal : IFractal
{
    public Fractal Root { get; }
    public Fractal Parent { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Fractal> Children { get; private set; }

    IFractal IFractal.Root => Root;
    IFractal IFractal.Parent => Parent;
    IEnumerable<IFractal> IFractal.Children => Children;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Обычно вот так делают:

```
interface IFractal<T> where T : IFractal<T>
```

Это позволит ходить по "навигационным" свойствам без знания конкретного типа T.

Comment: Я скорректировал свой код, но это не отвечает на вопрос. Мне по-прежнему нужно указывать Т, если я захочу объявить переменную типа IFractal<T>

Comment: @eastwing можно использовать обобщенные методы

Comment: не очень понял - где использовать? Если не сложно, приведите пример